# Pytest - How to assert whether a function have called monkeypatched methods

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I have a complex function that calls many other 3rd party methods. I monkeypatched them out one by one:

```
import ThirdParty as tp

def my_method():
  tp.func_3rd_party_1()
  ...
  tp.func_3rd_party_5()

  return "some_value"
```

In my test:

```
import pytest

def test_my_method(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(ThirdParty, 'func_3rd_party_1', some_mock_1())
    ...
    monkeypatch.setattr(ThirdParty, 'func_3rd_party_5', some_mock_5())

    return_value = my_method()
    assert return value
```

This runs just fine but the test feels too implicit for me in this form. I'd like to explicitly state that the monkeypatched methods were indeed called.

For the record, my mocked methods are not using any inbuilt Mock library resource. They are just redefined methods (smart stubs).

Is there any way to assert for that?

Comment: Can't you just explicitly ask the mock objects if they have been called in the way you want them to be called?

Comment: ```some_mock_1.assert_called_once()``` or any of the variations of the `assert_called`.

Comment: @Lagerbaer Thanks for the response! Is it that simple? For the record I'm not using any `Mock` objects, so they are just purely redefined functions by me.

Comment: Oh if you're using your own functions then `assert_called()` etc won't work; you'd have to grab a `Mock` or `MagicMock` from e.g. `unittest.mock`.

Comment: @Lagerbaer I wonder if it is compactly possible with monkeypatching, or that means I should swap from monkeypatch to `mock.patch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the pytest `monkeypatching` fixture is specifically provided so you can change some global attributes like environment variables, stuff in third party libraries, etc, to provide some controlled and easy behavior for your test.

The Mock objects, on the other hand, are meant to provide all sorts of tracking and inspection on the object.

The two go hand in hand: You use patching to replace some third party function with a Mock object, then execute your code, and then ask the Mock object if it has indeed been invoked with the right arguments, for the right number of times.

Note that even though the `mock` module is part of `unittest`, it works perfectly fine with `pytest`.

Now as for the patching itself, it's up to your personal preference, and depends a bit on what exactly you want to patch, whether using `unittest.mock.patch` is more compact or pytest's `monkeypatch` fixture.

```py
import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock

def test_my_method(monkeypatch):
    # refer to the mock module documentation for more complex 
    # set ups, where the mock object _also_ exhibits some behavior.
    # as is, calling the function doesn't actually _do_ anything.
    some_mock_1 = Mock()
    ...
    some_mock_5 = Mock(return_value=66)

    monkeypatch.setattr(ThirdParty, 'func_3rd_party_1', some_mock_1)
    ...
    monkeypatch.setattr(ThirdParty, 'func_3rd_party_5', some_mock_5)

    some_mock_1.assert_called_once()
    some_mock_5.assert_called_with(42)
    ...
```

Now a note on this type of testing: Don't go overboard! It can quite easily lead to what's called *brittle* tests: Tests that break with the slightest change to your code. It can make refactoring an impossible neightmare.

These types of assertions are best when you use them in a message-focused object-oriented approach. If the whole *point* of the class or method under test is to invoke, in a particular way, the method or class of another object, then Mock away. If the calls to third party functions on the other hand are merely a means to an end, then go a level higher with your test and test for the desired *behavior* instead.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I have one question, can I add a function to `Mock()` 's `return_value` arg?
I'm actually using a Microsoft `O365` python library to access drives and files from cloud. I had to create custom methods since not all logic is implemented. My method for example creates the proper folder directory and I have to call the library's `get_some_item` or `ċreate_some_folder_here` kinds of methods with the right loops/checks inside. Clearly I can't access real drives in tests so I had to mock these methods and objects out. Would you call this behavioral testing?

Comment: The `return_value` can be anything you like. If you don't set it yourself, it will automatically be a new Mock object, and so on. If you set it, you can for example pass in some dummy class or stub class.

So in your use case example, you're using Mocks to "stub out" a third-party dependency that's too expensive to test. That's certainly an appropriate use case for Mocks and patching.